# How can I set some values to some fields in an Ecto model on insert

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a couple of fields in an Ecto model for which I want to insert a) default value b) generate value when I'm doing an insert. How can I do that? In which function should I do that, in "changeset"?

Comment: Can you give an actual example? Default value can be set using `:default` option in https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#field/3 but that value will be evaluated at compile time so you cannot use something like `Ecto.DateTime.utc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the usual place for such things is the changeset function. If you need to differentiate what happens on insert and update, you can define multiple changeset functions and call the appropriate one when updating or inserting the data. For example:

```
defmodule MyApp.Schema do
  #...

  def insert_changeset(struct, params) do
    struct
    |> common_changeset(params)
    |> put_change(:foo, "bar") # writing a field to the changeset
    # ...
  end

  def update_changeset(struct, params) do
    struct
    |> common_changeset(params)
    # ...
  end

  defp common_changeset(struct, params) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:foo, :bar])
    # ...
  end
end
```

If the default value is a static one, you can also use ecto's `default:` option for the `field/3` macro in the schema - it's equivalent to providing a value for a field in the `defstruct` declaration.

Comment: what's the difference between put_change and update_change? put_change can also update a value like update_change does.

Comment: It's the same difference as between `Map.put/3` and `Map.update!/3` - the first one takes a new value, the second one takes a function transforming the old value to a new one.

Comment: put_change can insert if it doesn't exist and update a value if it exists, can't it?

Comment: Yes. You use those in a completely different way -> `put_change(changeset, :foo, "new value")` vs `update_change(changeset, :foo, &String.downcase/1)`

Comment: so what's the difference between them except the last argument?

Comment: I believe the documentation is pretty clear on that https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#put_change/3 and https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#update_change/3